# (next.js): webpack Error while running yarn dev

Tags: webpack, next.js

I successfully created next-app but when I run ( yarn dev ) I get this webpack error:

```
macbookpro@macs-MacBook-Pro-2 nextjs-nftmarketplace % yarn dev
yarn run v1.22.15
$ next dev
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - SWC minify release candidate enabled. https://nextjs.link/swcmin
event - compiled client and server successfully in 2.2s (169 modules)
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled successfully in 49 ms (142 modules)
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled successfully in 20 ms (27 modules)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: Unable to snapshot resolve dependencies
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: Unable to snapshot resolve dependencies
```

Any solutions for this?

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I have the same